# How to remove a series in Highcharts by name

Tags: javascript, highcharts, series

I'd like to remove certain series from my Highcharts graph when a user clicks on a button. But I'd like to delete these by using a name or id of the series, and not the item in an array.

So, instead of doing this:

```
    chart.series[1].remove();
```

I'd like to use:

```
    chart.series["Volcanoes"].remove();
```

However, I don't succeed in this. Anything wrong with this here:

```
    chart.addSeries(
    {
        name: "Volcanic",
        id: "Volcanic",
        data: [xxxx]
    });
```

Or how do I access the series by name? [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/6g5ttbfr/3/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get a seri by ID you should use `chart.get("SeriId")` and to remove it use below code:

```
chart.get('Volcanic').remove();
```

I edited your sample with this approach [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/1nro5Lss/)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot... BTW: Is there any documentation of that sort somewhere? How could I get to this without asking here? I guess it's less Highcharts-stuff, but jQuery-knowledge?

Comment: I'd like to remove the lines a bit less suddenly - that is, with some sort of "vanishing" effect. Any chance you'd know how?

Comment: @luftikus143, highcharts has a complete  [api reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) and  [complete documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs) in highchart website, you can also ask or search for questions about highcharts at [highchart user voice](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api) hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, sure, I know and consult these all the time. But I haven't stumbled over chart.get() command anywhere. But ok, I see now that the [Methods and Properties](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.get) section has that kind of information. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @luftikus143, unfortunately I didn't found animation on remove or hide seri, but I will search more and if I found somthing,I'll reply here